# I dont understand why i cant use user_choice later as its "not defined"

Tags: python, function

```py
def user_input():
    x = input("Choose :Charizard, Blastoise, or Venusaur: ")
    if x in "char":
        user_choice = "Charizard"
    elif x in "blast":
        user_choice = "Blastoise"
    elif x in "ven":
        user_choice = "Venusaur"
    return user_choice


user_input()

print(user_choice)
```

erorr = NameError: name 'user_choice' is not defined

I want to use user_choice later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are not saving what you are returning from the method

```
user_choice = user_input()
print(user_choice)
```

It will work that way

**Edit**

`if x in "char"` means that if x a substing of "char" return true. from my understanding you want to say that if x is exactly equals to "char" then `user_choice = "Charizard"` so the code will be like this:

```
def user_input():
     x = input("Choose :Charizard, Blastoise, or Venusaur: ")
     if x == "char":
        user_choice = "Charizard"
     elif == in "blast":
        user_choice = "Blastoise"
     elif == in "ven":
        user_choice = "Venusaur"
    return user_choice

user_choice = user_input()
print(user_choice)
```

[image: sample]

Comment: There are also multiple errors like 
if x in "char"
won't work

Please post the whole working answer

Comment: There are still many errors x == "char"? will it work?
Try to run the code first and then post an answer.

Wrong answers give -ve impact to the community.

Comment: Code is asking to `Choose :Charizard, Blastoise, or Venusaur`
but you are typing `char`. Both of them are different things.

Comment: check my solution below. That is what I am trying to say.

Comment: I was following  the original question code. I think it's obvious to replace `char` with `Charizard` if you want that behavior. I think the answer provide the explanation of what goes wrong and how to fix it. I can't predict what you are thinking to code it for you :)

Comment: Yup! Fair Enough :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking why wasn't `user_choice` just given the value of `None` it's because you never defined `user_choice` if none of those if statements aren't true.

You want your code to be more like this. There are multiple errors in your code, I've fixed them all.

```
def user_input():
    user_choice = "" # Defined user_choice before taking the input
    x = input("Choose :Charizard, Blastoise, or Venusaur: ")
    if "char" in x:
        user_choice = "Charizard"
    elif "blast" in x:
        user_choice = "Blastoise"
    elif "ven" in x:
        user_choice = "Venusaur"
    return user_choice


print(user_input()) # This prints the value of the object returned by the function
```

Comment: There are also multiple errors
`"char" in x` id user types charizard then only it will work. not with Charizard.

Answer (score 1):

You have it backward basically, You would want to check if those characters are in the string as opposed to the opposite. See below:

```
def user_input():
    x = input("Choose :Charizard, Blastoise, or Venusaur: ")
    if "Char" in x:
        user_choice = "Charizard"
    elif "Blast" in x:
        user_choice = "Blastoise"
    elif "Ven" in x:
        user_choice = "Venusaur"
    return user_choice

print(user_input())
```

But I would suggest you make your code a bit more robust by maybe presenting the choices as number and they enter a number from a list. You could also add some validation to make sure they only enter one of those three names so you never get that undefined error.

**EDIT**

Also, as some other pointed out you are not saving the output of your return. For example whenever you have any function lets say:

```
def main():
    return 'Hello World'
```

if you call `x = main()` then `x='Hello World'` in your example you are trying to access that variable outside of the scope and not saving the return of the function anywhere. Take a look at the code I have and it should run how you want it.

Comment: I highlighted that at the bottom. Did you not read the full answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `user_choice` is a local variable in the function and you do not pass the variable outside the function. Therefore `user_choice` is None when you print it.

Comment: There are also multiple errors like 
if x in "char"
won't work

Please post whole working answer

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Errors in your code

1st one is the best solution for it but below them are solutions if you want to write it according to your code

It's your choice you can use any one of the solutions but I would suggest the 1st one.

```
def user_input():
    x = input("Choose :Charizard, Blastoise, or Venusaur: ")
    if x in ['Charizard', 'Blastoise', 'Venusaur']:
        return x
    return str()
user_choice = user_input()
print(user_choice)
```

---

```
def user_input():
    x = input("Choose :Charizard, Blastoise, or Venusaur: ")
    if "Char" in x:
        user_choice = "Charizard"
    elif "Blast" in x:
        user_choice = "Blastoise"
    elif "Ven" in x:
        user_choice = "Venusaur"
    else:
        user_choice = str()
    return user_choice
user_choice = user_input()
print(user_choice)
```

---

```
def user_input():
    x = input("Choose :Charizard, Blastoise, or Venusaur: ")
    user_choice = str()
    if "Char" in x:
        user_choice = "Charizard"
    elif "Blast" in x:
        user_choice = "Blastoise"
    elif "Ven" in x:
        user_choice = "Venusaur"
    return user_choice
user_choice = user_input()
print(user_choice)
```

Try to understand it and let me know if it needs to be explained :)

Answer (score 0):

Needless to be too wordy that `user_input` is out of scope that is where `print` is. Hint: Do you know scope-specifier in Python? *(Shush! Be quiet! Spaces)*